# Grails GORM HQL Number of Rows Return by Group By Query

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

Can anyone help me to write equivalent HQL query for GORM of following query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT cast(t.disburse_time AS DATE))
FROM transactions_details t
WHERE (t.status_id = 5 OR t.status_id = 6 OR t.status_id = 7)
ORDER BY t.disburse_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Transactions_details.createCriteria().list() {
            projections {
                countDistinct( 'disburse_time' )
            }
            'in' ( 'status_id', [5,6,7] )
            order 'disburse_time'
        }
```

Comment: Is there any HQL query for this, I need HQL because I need to add more where condition dynamically. @Mike_W

Comment: You can add conditions in the example above e.g. after the projections block